# iOS Voiceover: Focus selected cell and not the first row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, focus, accessibility

I trying to make my app accessible, in my interface I have a UILabel and a UITableView, the tableView have a selectedRow. The selectedRow is the row in the middle of table view, for example is the row 50 if I have 100 row.

My problem is when I swype in screen to go to my next element, in this case when I go from label to tableView, the focus go to the first index and not to my cell was selected.

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have only a label and a table view, the problem boils down to keep in mind the latest position of the cell when you move from the label to the table view.

The following algorithm may be used to solve this problem :

- Create a temporary index path variable (`tmpIP`) containing the index path of the selected cell.
- When the label loses the focus, the table view selects the cell with the latest `tmpIP` index path. The variable value is nil if no cell was selected before the label selection.

[image]

Take a look at the `UIAccessibilityFocus` [informal protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibilityfocus) to handle the focus of an accessible element.

Comment: Playing with lostFocus more or less that work, but I have to refine, thank for the help